# divide a web page to two pages

Tags: split, html

I know how to divide a web page using `<div>`s
, but I want each divided section to have its own back and forward and address bar. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: So... You want to add a browser inside a div?

Comment: ok, how I can have two browsers in one page?

Comment: If you use Firefox, then chrome://browser/content/browser.xul

Comment: I use IE 7. Is it possible for that?

Comment: Oh dear, no, I was being a bit silly to be honest. I don't know what you need a browser in a browser for, but I'd advise against it - or, use iframes as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: let's explain more maybe you have a better solution for me. I have number of buttons in my page. when one of them is clicked a webpage should be displayed. I want this webpage be displayed in the same page that the button exits.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using one physical web page and have 2 sets of the browser's default controls, no.

You could create two HTML pages, each representing half the original page and then display them in two browser windows, sized identically and positioned adjacent to each other.

Otherwise use - ugh - iframes!

**EDIT:** If you really want a browser in a browser, then open Firefox and visit 
chrome://browser/content/browser.xul

Comment: I use IE 7. Is it possible for that?